# Splash Screen And Activity with asset manager

Tags: android, performance, splash-screen, android-assets, android-assetmanager

My app contains a lot of assets that i am using with AssetManager. Currently my app is taking too long to start up. How can i solve this? or is there any way to show a Splash Screen till the assets are loaded and the next activity is loaded?

Comment: What type of contents do you have in your `Asset`

Comment: You can use flutter:  https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-splash-screen-9f4e05542548

Comment: jpg image file only

Comment: @AsfaqueAhmed And those images are loaded in the splash screen right?

Comment: They are loaded in first activity. 
So that the activity is taking lang time actually.

Comment: The activity is taking time to load because the of the resolution of those .jpg images. I has the same problem. What is the resolution of your images @AsfaqueAhmed This will also increase the size of your .apk file.

Comment: Total 7mb image